# Tempdb data file disappearing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb, datafile

I recently moved my Temp database files onto a separate drive (I had two data files and one log file).

However, after restarting the server, my second data file disappeared both from the file list on the gui and from sp_helpfile. I've managed to reproduce this behaviour several times: I add a new data file, see it appear both in the gui and sp_helpfile, and disappear after rebooting the server.

I've run `dbcc checkdb` against the database and it returns no errors. There's no information either in the SQL logs or the windows application event log.

After doing a little more research, I ran the following query:

```
select d.name, m.* from sys.master_files m
inner join sys.databases d 
on (m.database_id = d.database_id)
where d.name like 'tempdb'
order by 1, 2
```

Results: http://pastebin.com/Zu5fJ2hU

It shows four different secondary data files, none of which appear in sp_helpfile. If I try to use any of those names SQL server doesn't allow me to. None of these files physically exist on the disk. My server is SQL 2012 Standard.

Comment: What edition are you using? How exactly are you adding files to tempdb?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sql server 2012 (as tagged :)). I'm adding them through the gui by clicking "add" on the files page of the database properties window. I've done it this way in the past many times with no issues.

Comment: That's a version, not an edition. Are you using Express, for example?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oops, my mistake. Standard edition.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this starting with a new database? If so, could you please provide a test script?

Comment: @JonSeigel This is a production server, so it's going to be difficult to duplicate the "restart the server" part. I've tried creating a new database and detaching/attaching, but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: @JonSeigel While I was working on this, I had an idea - I looked at the permissions on the tempdb .ndf file that it seemed not to know about, and sure enough the managed service account had no permissions to it. I added the permissions manually and sp_helpfile shows that file now (but I haven't been able to restart the server). Does this help?

Comment: @JonSeigel I've reproduced this behaviour: Creating a new database does not give the service accounts any permission on the MDF/LDF files. Not sure if this is expected behaviour, or problematic?

Comment: Since you moved the files and this started happening, and given what you found, check that the service account has the correct permissions assigned in the new location -- it should have Full Control on This Folder, Subfolders, and Files starting at the data container root.

Comment: @JonSeigel It didn't have any of that (I added it). Assuming that works (the tempdb data file hasn't disappeared yet); how do I go about cleaning up those orphaned file records?

Comment: I'd start by trying `ALTER DATABASE tempdb REMOVE FILE ...`. If that doesn't work, something more invasive may be necessary. Depending on the criticality of the server, it may be best to just leave it alone if everything is working as it is.

Comment: @JonSeigel Okay, that seems to have worked. I guess I'll have to reboot the server to really see if things stick, but those orphaned files are gone now at least.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it was that easy to get rid of those rows. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>(Consolidating the comments into an answer, so it's more easily consumable by searchers.)</sup>

It appears this is related to not granting the appropriate permissions to the data container when moving the location of the physical files. Without having tried it, I believe this would also apply to user databases, not just `tempdb`.

I have an old, but still technically accurate, video on how to move all the system databases (not just `tempdb`) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAlgpxjJCiM), which includes showing the process of assigning permissions to the new data container. The database engine requires Full Control on This Folder, Subfolders, and Files starting at the data container root.

After the permissions are set correctly on the data container, the dangling files should be removable from the system catalogs using [`ALTER DATABASE ... REMOVE FILE ...`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for posting! I'll reboot the server this weekend, and if everything continues to be fine I'll mark as answer/award the bounty.

Comment: @Mansfield: Thanks! I'm glad the solution was relatively simple. :)